# Virtual Assistant Typescript / Authentication (New Skill or Modify GeneratedCode)

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, botframework

I have created a virtual assistant in typescript and modify the .lu files for LUIS and QnA purposes; then i could deploy it to azure. Now, I would like to add authentication to verify only domain users are authorized to use the bot.
Samples of botframework shows this feature configuration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth) and could be used in a similar way that 2 examples does: one doing the [oauth authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication) against AzureAD and the other one [interacting with GraphApi](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) to get information about current authenticated user. Both starts with a simple bot generation or echo bot.

When i try to add the authentication feature to the [generated virtual asistant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-botbuilder-assistant), what is the recommended practice: to modify the generated source code or create a new skill with this feature?. Does the last one, implies to add a new webapp to the solution?

Comment: I don't believe there is a right or wrong approach here. For a standard bot built using the Bot Framework, OAuth is baked into the code. However, the general concept behind the Virtual Assistant is to utilize skills to "modularize" functionality. That being said, I don't think you would be amiss if you simply put the code in the source. I don't see a need to built a new skill (i.e. bot) for login unless something more fanciful is happening there.

Comment: I'm agree with you; however there is a set of helper classes and methods to do the authentication already added inside virtual assistant {[buildAuthDialog in index.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/Virtual-Assistant-Template/typescript/samples/sample-assistant/src/index.ts), [activation of skills in mainDialog.ts ]() and [usage of graph for authenticated clients in graphClient.ts]() }, but there are not rules explained in documentation to make it work, unless you add a new skill.

Comment: ... so if there is already a code that seems that makes some authentication procedures if you add an skill, why not to used instead of a change in the generated code of virtual assistant.